# __EVENTVALIDATION and __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR placement

Tags: .net, iis

How do I change where .NET places the the _EVENTVALIDATION and __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR hidden fields when it servers up a page. I have an updatePanel that works fine in development but does not work on the production server. Everything is up to date on both the development and production servers and I know updatePanels do work on the production server. When I "view source" in the browser, the development server (visual studio 2013 iis express) is serving the page with the _EVENTVALIDATION and __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR hidden fields at the end of the form tag but the production server is serving the page placing them at the beginning of the form tag. Nothing else is different. How can I force .NET to place these fields at the end of the form tag instead of the beginning? Don't ask me why a hidden field would cause a problem, it just is.